# How to change focus after scaling view?

Tags: android, focus, scale, android-relativelayout

To scale view I use next code:

```
 relativeLayout.setScaleX(scale);
 relativeLayout.setScaleY(scale);
```

But after it I have the next:[1](http://i59.tinypic.com/2s0jm9u.png)

So it is offset. I need to make it not offset.

I need to add some thing like pivot point for canvas but it must be for view.

Comment: And what the question?

Comment: I scaled black one. I need to put him in the top left angle

Comment: what you exactly want ...your question is not clear to understand so let add some more information

Comment: I need to make it not offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found:
 relativeLayout.setPivotX(0f);
 relativeLayout.setPivotY(0f);